# Wifi Outgoing Calling Options for iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, wifi, wifi-calling

I have an iPhone 5s with Verizon wireless.  I just moved into a new house and the cellular service is very weak, however my home Wifi is great.  I tried to look into calling over wifi, however this feature isn't available on the iPhone 5s's apple menu as it's a pretty old phone.  What options do I have to accept/send calls on wifi?

I tried google voice however the only feature I can use is to create a # with them and forward that to my real #.  Ideally I'd like to use my real # to accept calls and make calls over wifi.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this Verizon site](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/wifi-calling-faqs/) with their wifi calling FAQ's.  If this feature isn't available in the iPhone settings then your only option is to upgrade to a more modern iPhone.

Comment: [This page](https://www.lifewire.com/top-voip-apps-for-ios-3426476) may help you explore other options. [This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi+calling+apps+ios&oq=wifi+calling+apps+ios) which you could have done before asking here, gives other options.